# Function keeps overwriting previous structure data

Tags: c++

when I enter data using my add function, I am able to print them no problem. Adding a vaule for start(x,y), end(x,y) works and I am able to print the values. But when I specify that I want two numGraphicElements when the function leaves after entering the first set of start and end values. It overwrites my previous values when going through the loop a second time.

When I print the values it for some reason overwrites my first values with random numbers and then only shows the second set of start(x,y) end(x,y) values.

example of first set: start(1,2) end (3,4)....this print properly

example of second set added: start(9,8) end (6,7)...this prints as well

example pf print out with 2 sets together, x(23424), y(653243), end = x(2334) y(33434).....x(9) y(8) end x(3) y(4).

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <crtdbg.h>

#define _CRTDBG_MAP_ALLOC

enum
{
  RUNNING = 1
};

struct Point
{
  int x, y;
};

struct Line
{
  Point start;
  Point end;
};

struct GraphicElement
{
  enum
  {
    SIZE = 256
  };
  unsigned int numLines; //number of lines
  Line* pLines; //plines points to start and end
  char name[SIZE];
};

typedef struct
{
  unsigned int numGraphicElements;
  GraphicElement* pElements; //the head points to pLines
} VectorGraphic;

void InitVectorGraphic(VectorGraphic*);
void AddGraphicElement(VectorGraphic*);
void ReportVectorGraphic(VectorGraphic*);

VectorGraphic Image;

int main()
{
  char response;
  InitVectorGraphic(&Image);

  //for debugging purposes
  _CrtSetDbgFlag(_CRTDBG_ALLOC_MEM_DF | _CRTDBG_LEAK_CHECK_DF);

  //main menu for the program
  while (RUNNING)
  {
    printf("\nPlease select an option:\n");
    printf("1. Add a Graphic Element\n");
    printf("2. List the Graphic Elements\n");
    printf("q. Quit\n");
    printf("CHOICE: ");
    fflush(stdin);
    scanf("%c", &response);

    switch (response)
    {
    case '1':
      AddGraphicElement(&Image);
      break;
    case '2':
      ReportVectorGraphic(&Image);
      break;
    case 'q':
      CleanUpVectorGraphic(&Image);
      return 0;
    default:
      printf("Please enter a valid option\n");
    }
    printf("\n");
  }
}

/*initialize the vectors, allocate memory*/
void InitVectorGraphic(VectorGraphic * pImage)
{ //addres of pImage is passed in
  struct GraphicElement *pElements;
  pImage->pElements = (GraphicElement*) malloc(sizeof(GraphicElement)); //pImage is now the addess of image
  pElements = (GraphicElement*) malloc(sizeof(GraphicElement));
  pImage->numGraphicElements = 8;
  pImage->pElements = NULL;
}
```

Comment: You seem to be using a C++ compiler. A C compiler would complain the about the missing type `GraphicElement`.

Comment: @alk Im not entirely sure why my initial values are being over written with garbage values

Comment: This **is** C++ code, not C code. Don't use C programming-style in C++. They are different languages. See [ask] and provide a [mcve].

Comment: VS also can run in C (alike) mode.

Comment: @alk: If you mean me, I know that (but not standard C). But the code apparently is C++. `struct Point`/`Point start` etc. are clear indicators. As OP already uses C++, he should use inheritance. `Point` and `Line` are soo typical for beginners to learn OOP.

Comment: I assumed you know this @Olaf.And also please note my addition to my previous comment ...  ;-)

Comment: You have removed the critical code, so now the questions is incomplete ... :-(

Answer (score 1):

Here

```
line = (struct Line *) malloc(sizeof(Line));
```

the code allocates exactly *one* line-object.

Here its seems to address more then just `line[0]`:

```
line[pImage->numGraphicElements]....
```

Doing so the code invokes undefined behaviour, anything can happen from this moment on. This includes overwriting other memory belonging to the same process.

Comment: Is that why the first 4 values are overwritten after I add a second set of graphic elements?

Comment: How would I avoid overwriting if I add another set of elements?

Comment: @Calidreaminn: Perhaps, I did not search for other mistakes after I discovered the one mentioned in my answer. Fix it and see what happens.

Comment: @Calidreaminn: "*avoid overwriting*": Allocate room for as many line objects as needed. If not know in advance re-allocate what's already there.

Comment: The only fix that I could think of is line->start;..

Comment: @Calidreaminn: To be honest I have no clue what the code is intended to do in detail. I just pointed you to something that cannot work.